# How to locate element without id,name and xpath in webdriver selenium google chrome

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

how can i locate element td without name , id attributes?

```
<tr class="odd" onmouseover="this.className='highlight'" onmouseout="this.className='odd'">
        <td style="width:4%;">J199</td> 
        <td style="width:5%;">056962840</td>    
        <td style="width:3%;">S</td>    
        <td style="width:5%;">11</td>   
        <td style="width:7%;">0606353</td>  
        <td style="width:7%;">4846962</td>  
        <td style="width:3%;">1</td>    
        <td style="width:20%;">S1-4100181163-MANUAL</td>    
        <td style="width:5%;">2019-07-03</td>   
        <td style="width:5%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:5%;cursor: pointer;"><span title="CSARL-SB/SINGAPORE PARTS DC">Y850</span></td>        
        <td style="width:5%;">2019-09-04</td>       
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

i only want to locate 
`<td style="width:5%;">2019-09-04</td>`
and call it in python `webdriver`

Comment: Why do you say that you cannot access this element with XPath? Is there any particaluar reason that XPath cannot be used in your setup?

Comment: oh sorry im new to selenium, is there a way to access this element with xpath? can u teach me

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with XPath, but might require a little bit more context, possibly even the entire HTML document. If the element you want to select is always the second column from the right in all odd columns, the XPath would look like this:
`//tr[@class = 'odd']/td[position() = last() -1]`
Probably in your case you need to find a specific odd column within a table? Then the predicate for your `tr` would have to be adjusted.

Comment: yes it worked. But there are 2 results. the `tr` falls under this table  `id =boresulttable_table`. Is there a way to add this inside xpath and make sure there is only 1 result? Thanks!

Comment: There are certainly ways to select the proper table and make sure there is only 1 result. But again, to make sure the XPath expression hits the right table cell requires some more context and knowledge about your application. 
Adding the table id gives `//table[@id = 'boresulttable_table']//tr[@class = 'odd']/td[position() = last() -1]` If this table has more than two odd rows, it will still give you more than one results, though. You can limit your XPath to only return the first result by appending `[1]` or to the second result with `[2]` to the end of the XPath expression.

Comment: @Fenio , you tagged this question with Python, but I don't think this question is Python-related. Asking about locators in Selenium is quite agnostic to any particular language bindings.

Comment: @KaiWeber Not necessarily. If you guy will have to provide the solution using `find_elements` and looping over them - it will also be `python` related. It's just an assumption

Comment: @Fenio I see. My fight against the exclusion of XPath as a possible solution to rob's problem has blinded me a little and prevented me to think in the direction of more Python-specific solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the `<td>` with text as **2019-09-04** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and element position:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//tr[@class='odd' and contains(@onmouseover, 'highlight')]//following-sibling::td[12]")))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and title *CSARL-SB/SINGAPORE PARTS DC*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@title, 'CSARL-SB/SINGAPORE PARTS DC')]//following::td[1]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match [`<td>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) having the text of `2019-09-04` it would be something like:

```
//td[text()='2019-09-04']
```

If you want to match the `<td>` tag which is before the last `<td>` tag go for [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) and [last()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/last) functions combination:

```
//td[position()=last()-1]
```

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)